# C freeing up dynamically allocated structure array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, dynamic-arrays

Excuse me if this has already been discussed to death but I cannot seem to find anything that relates to the issue I am having. In the code below I am trying to create an array of structures that will be passed along to many different functions. I need to dynamically allocate the array as it varies based on the number of instructions the user inputs. I am not sure if my declaration of the variable of my use of malloc() is incorrect but on every run I experience a break point on the free(instruction) line. I have also tried placing the free(instruction) line outside of the if statement but it yields the same result.This is a homework assignment and any hints or explanation will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct instructions
{
    char destination_register[3],
        reg1[3],
        reg2[3];        //declaration of destination and source registers.
    int delay;
};

struct instructions* instruction;

int main() {

    int input=0;
    char test1[2];
    int test,numberofinstructions=0;

    do {
        printf ("Pipelined instruction performance\n"
                "1) Enter instructions\n"
                "2) Determine when instructions are fetched\n"
                "3) Exit\n"
                "Enter selection : ");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if (input==1) {
            printf ("Enter number of instructions: ");
            scanf ("%d", &numberofinstructions);

            instruction = (struct instructions*) malloc(numberofinstructions + 
                            1 * sizeof(struct instructions));
            enterinstructs (instruction, numberofinstructions);

            printf("\n");
            free (instruction);
        }
    } while (input != 3);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Your `free (instruction);` destroys the object `instruction` sent to the function `enterinstructs()`. If `instruction` needs to survive longer than a single iteration, then move the `free()` outside the loop (though you will need an array in that case to avoid overwriting your pointer on subsequent allocations). If it doesn't need to survive more than 1 iteration, then using a struct with *automatic storage duration* is fine (just pass the address of the struct, e.g. using `&yourdeclaredstruct`). None of the struct members are a pointer, so there is no dynamic allocation required.

Comment: I was unsure if that was needed thank you. I have since moved the free outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you want  to this:

```
instruction = (struct instructions*) malloc(numberofinstructions + 1 * sizeof(struct instructions));
```

Here what happened is you allocated space `sizeof(struct instructions)` + `numberofinstructions` Which is meaningless.

What you want to do is probably:

```
instruction = (struct instructions*) malloc((numberofinstructions + 1) * sizeof(struct instructions));
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue I was having. I can't believe I overlooked that.